# Visio 2010 won't open .VSDX file?

Tags: visio, file-extension, corruption

Hey so I made a crows foot database ERD in Visio 2013 at home and now am trying to open the .VSDX file in Visio 2010 at work and I get an error message saying the file is corrupt or is not a visio file.

The file can't be corrupt as I used it just fine at home and it obviously is a Visio file. Is there some type of update or extension I can install to fix this?

Comment: Advice from MS is that you'll need to Save As... .VSD in Visio 2013, as the VSDX format is not backward compatible. This might help you: http://blogs.office.com/2012/09/10/vsdx-the-new-visio-file-format/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the Compatibility Pack, see this KB:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2844302

The compatibility pack itself is here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39640

Comment: This didn't work for me. I successfully installed the compatibility pack, but Visio 2010 will still not open `vsdx` files.

Comment: Make sure you install `Visio 2010 SP2` or it won't work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2844302/you-cannot-open-vsdx-or-vsdm-files-in-visio-2010

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me......I was using Office 2013 with Visio 2013.  Went to Firefox menu (3 hash marks on far right) > options > application > type visio in the search bar > it pulled up ms-visio as content type and I changed the action from "use Microsoft Visio" to Use "Microsoft Office 2013" - there was no save or close, but the changes were accepted. Closed the tab for options and tried to open Visio and it worked!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Typing "visio" in the application type search bar turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file in visio 2013 first then

1. from **file** menu choose **save as**
2. then from **save as type** choose **2003-2010 drawing**
3. click ok

The new file now is can be opened using Visio 2010.

[this solution here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compatibility-between-different-versions-of-visio-e17862db-a502-47a7-85dd-194fdfde67d2).

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]